# How to find out the PKCS of a PublicKey - Cryptography

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, public-key

A simple question but trick for me to know how to do it.

I received a Public Key from the client and I'd like to know which Standard this public key is following.

I.e: PKCS#1, PKCS#2, PKCS#3 and so on.

Why do I need it?
Because I want validate a signature given that I already have the signature and the text encrypted.

Comment: parse it with parsers? https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp

Comment: If it is PEM, just looking at the words on the dashes-BEGIN line tells you all you need to know. But there are many formats that aren't PEM. Some, like XMLdsig and JWK, are obviously self-descriptive; others are not. PGP 'armor' will similarly on the first line tell that it _is_ a key, but not details about it.

Answer (score 2):

Most PKCS don't involve public keys at all. All are listed in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS).

PKCS1 defines ASN.1 formats for publickey and privatekey for RSA (only). These are pretty much the only keys *described* as conforming to any PKCS.

PKCS2-4 and 6 no longer exist, although OpenSSL has caused the PKCS3 format for DH to persist -- but DH is not used for signature.

PKCS5 doesn't involve publickey.

PKCS7 can use publickeys for encryption and/or signature verification of a message and/or can convey one or more X.509 certificate(s) (each) *containing* a publickey. Such certificate(s) can be for any algorithm.

PKCS8 doesn't involve publickey.

PKCS9 doesn't directly involve any key, although some attributes can be used in an X.509 certificate for a publickey.

PKCS10 is used to request an X.509 certificate, and represents a publickey in the same way as that certificate, which can be for any algorithm.

PKCS11 is an interface; although many types of keys can be transferred over it, those keys are not 'PKCS11' keys.

PKSC12 in practice contains a publickey only as an X.509 certificate, for any algorithm.

So if a key is described as 'PKCS' it's almost certainly PKCS1 and thus RSA. But many publickey algorithms now exist and are more or less widely used (DSA/DH/MQV/EG some, ECDSA/ECDH/ECIES and EdDSA/X a lot, GOST a little, postquantum little but growing) that are not covered by any PKCS.